# python(scipy)-- setting an array element with a sequence error

Tags: python, scipy

i want to create a program which calculates the average of N random numbers taken from a uniform random number distribution.The program must run for
Ν=10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000 random numbers.Then,i have to plot the mean value as
a function of N.

I did this:

```
from scitools.std import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N=10

distribution=[]
for i in range(1,7):   
    N*=10
    random_numbers=[random.uniform(0,1,size=N)]   
    distribution.append(random_numbers)


plt.semilogx(array(range(N)),array(distribution).mean())
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

It gives me the error in the title in the line where i do the plot.
Also,if there is another ,more pythonic way of doing this i'll appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: It is in the title:setting an array element with a sequence (Valueerror)

Comment: Take the mean of random_numbers before adding it to distribution.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.I chose the most pythonic.Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ns=[10**i for i in range(1,7)]
means=[scipy.random.uniform(0,1,size=N).mean() for N in Ns]

plt.semilogx(Ns,means)
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

1. As has already been mentioned, `distribution` is a list of arrays,
   with the inner arrays having different shapes. You can't form a numpy
   array out of such an object by calling `np.array(distribution)`.
2. At least for plotting purposes, you don't need to save the entire
   distribution. Just compute and store the means. A succinct way to do
   that is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
3. [Don't use `from module import *` in scripts](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import). It makes it hard
   to trace where variables come from. The `from module import *` was
   made (mainly) for use in interactive sessions, but generally not recommended for scripts.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the tips!I use import * because some times its difficult to know what method goes where.

Comment: It pays to take the time to sort it out now, and save examples of how you use various functions so you can cut-and-paste later. Doing `from scipy import *` is particularly dangerous because `scipy.any` is a different function than Python's builtin `any`. `from scipy import *` overwrites Python's builtin `any`, making it harder to access (and a potential source of bugs).

Answer (score 1):

Compute the mean() before adding the random numbers to the distribution list.  Then you have a simple plot of an n-element list.  The problem is that you needed a list of scalars, not a list of arrays:

```
distribution=[]
for i in range(1,7):   
    N*=10
    random_numbers=[random.uniform(0,1,size=N)]   
    distribution.append(array(random_numbers).mean())
```

Comment: +1. Just for the sake of completeness, I'll add a bit of explanation:  The OP's conversion `array(distribution)` didn't work because it tried to convert a list of one-dimensional arrays of different lengths to a NumPy array, which is not possible.  `map(numpy.mean, distribution)` would also work in the original code.

Comment: The problem with the above code is that the "mean" method doesn't work because random_numbers is a list.If i make it array,then it gives me error:must have same first dimension

Comment: A list of scalars should be convertible to an array so you can take the mean.

Comment: This works fine:  ``>>> numpy.random.uniform(0,1,10).mean()`` --> ``0.48908919057971734``

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be appending a list in a list, like this:

```
a = [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Try this code instead:

```
for i in range(1, 7):   
    N*=10
    distribution.append(random.uniform(0,1,size=N))
```

---

@Raymond suggests to take the mean of the sequence:

```
plt.semilogx(array(range(N)),array(sum(distribution) / float(len(distribution))))
```